# UINavigationBar tintColor is misbehaving

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar, swift5, tintcolor

I have issue when set UINavigationBar tintColor.

It is misbehaving

I'm using xcode 11.3.1, swift 5, iOS 13.3

*MyClass

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.title = "test"
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9708816409, green: 0.4246639013, blue: 0.3480253518, alpha: 1)
}
```

*result

1. real device
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/TB3Sp.jpg
2. simulator
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMV7n.jpg

I want to set back button color like title

I only get error on real device

Please help me

Thank you

Comment: For ios13+ follow the official guideline: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/customizing_your_app_s_navigation_bar. Change self.navigationController?.view... to self.navigationController?.navigationBar...

Comment: thank you ugur. I did and nothing change

Answer (score 0):

To set back button and hide "back":

```
let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
        backItem.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9708816409, green: 0.4246639013, blue: 0.3480253518, alpha: 1)
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
```

You should but this code to the `ViewController` before push the new one.

Comment: thank you Ahmed Abd Elaziz. I did but nothing change

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `UIColor` instead of `#colorLiteral`?

Like

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.9708816409, green: 0.4246639013, blue: 0.3480253518, alpha: 1)

//or

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 0.9708816409, green: 0.4246639013, blue: 0.3480253518, alpha: 1)
```

Edit: 
Since that the above did not work for you, did you try this?

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = self.navigationController?.navigationItem.titleView?.backgroundColor
```

Considering that all you want is to have both the button and title to have the same colour right?

Comment: thank you vincent, I tried UIColor with Content sRBG and DisplayP3 but nothing change

Comment: @toiyeu I have edited to add another answer. Do update me if it works

Comment: I tried with     
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.9708816409, green: 0.4246639013, blue: 0.3480253518, alpha: 1).    
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = self.navigationController?.navigationItem.titleView?.backgroundColor

Comment: and back Button color is default system blue

Comment: @toiyeu if you are using the same color for the whole app, maybe this could help: https://stephenradford.me/quick-tip-globally-changing-tint-color-application-wide/

Answer (score 0):

Try access to *navigationController.navigationBar* instead of *navigationController.view* :

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9708816409, green: 0.4246639013, blue: 0.3480253518, alpha: 1)
```

Comment: thanh you UnuSynth. I edited my question. I tried but nothing change